# Synonym [stove] and [range]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[stove](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stove) (192 questions) seems to be the more popular tag, and it has an excerpt.

[range](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range) (86 questions, 16 also tagged [stove](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stove)) is simply referring to the same thing.

In this same vein, it might be worth adding a synonym for [glass-top-range](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass-top-range) as well (7 questions)

Comment: A stove, oven, and range are technically 3 different things, though many people use the terms interchangeably. The stove is the cook top. The oven is the compartment for baking. And the range is a single appliance with both an oven and a stove.

Comment: @BMitch How about adding/updating text for the tags - stove has some text, range & glass-top-range have none.

Comment: @manassehkatz done.

Comment: I guess we can mark this [status-completed] then